# Retrieve all possible values for a REFERENCE field

Tags: apex, soql

How can I retrieve all possible values for a REFERENCE field.

I mean such a field that

```
Schema.SObjectField field = doesNotMatter();
String fieldName = field+'';
//fieldName now holds "NameOfTheField"
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = field.getDescribe();
String typeName = fieldResult.getType()+'';
//typeName now holds "REFERENCE"
```

I know that this is a field of a `SomeObj` object.

Thank you.

After an answer I try to write some code. Should I do something like this (I mean the code below)?

```
List<Schema.sObjectType> res = fieldResult.getReferenceTo();
List<String> names = new List<String>();
for(Schema.sObjectType obj) {
   names.add(obj.getName());
}
```

And now I believe I should retrieve all ids of all records in all objects from `names`. I am sure that I can do it using SOSL, but I do not know how exactly. Could you help me to do that, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`Schema.DescribeFieldResult.getReferenceTo()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe) provides a list of all of the sObject types to which that reference field can point.

For custom lookup fields, this will be a list of size 1. For polymorphic lookups, such as `Task.WhoId` and `Task.WhatId`, as well as `OwnerId` for objects that can be owned by Queues, this will be a list of some size greater than one, potentially quite large.

Based on your comments and edits, you are trying to establish all possible values for this field in an effort to build something like a dynamic query interface. I would strongly suggest not trying to do this by generating a list of all extant Ids. Running unfiltered queries against large objects like

```
SELECT Id FROM SomeObject__c
```

can quickly run you into limits trouble if your org has substantial data volume. But even before you hit limits problems, you'll have issues with your user experience. Ids are generally not user-facing because they're opaque (unlike, for example, the `Name` field), and even a list of a couple of hundred record Ids will be impossible to navigate from a UI standpoint.

Instead, I would suggest that you either (a) provide some other type of search interface to locate potential lookup field targets, or (b) allow the user to enter a record Id and then validate it upon data entry, or (c) allow your users to filter based on *user-facing properties*, like record names, rather than Ids.

Comment: I updated my question a little bit. Could you, please, help me to write a SOSL query. Writing it will truly allow me to get all possible values (which are ids I believe, so List<Id> in other words will be the result of my question) for the `"REFERENCE"` field. Thank you.

Comment: You are not going to be able to do that easily on-platform. You are limited to 50,000 SOQL rows, and the SOSL limit is even lower. This looks like an x-y problem to me: what is your real objective?

Comment: I have an object. That object has fields. I am writing a custom lightning component. This component should allow user to pick a field using dropdown and then apply restrictions on the field. For example, I am picking a `"REFERENCE"` field, there is another dropdown in which I pick an equal operator, and in the third dropdown I am picking a value from all the available values for the `"REFERENCE"` field. And then (I think it is not important for the issue, but I will tell) I will use this restriction to show the user only such records of the object which has the restriction satisfied.