# Retrieve Ids of different SObjects using SOSL

Tags: apex, sosl, id

I have the following apex:

```
Schema.SObjectField field = doesNotMatter();
String fieldName = field+'';
//fieldName now holds "NameOfTheField"
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = field.getDescribe();
String typeName = fieldResult.getType()+'';
//typeName now holds "REFERENCE"
List<Schema.sObjectType> res = fieldResult.getReferenceTo();
List<String> names = new List<String>();
for(Schema.sObjectType obj) {
   names.add(obj.getName());
}
```

Now I would like to query all the ids of all the records of objects whose names are in `names` list. How can I do that? I am not worried about the number of records returned, since I always can append `LIMIT` to the query.

I am just continuing [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239409/retrieve-all-possible-values-for-a-reference-field) question.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey @yourbuddy, what do you need?  What contains the names list? I understand that you have a list like names = new String[]{'Account','Opportunity'} and you want to get all the record ids of these objects, Did I understand good?

Comment: @Torsen, I updated my question a little bit. Thank you.

Comment: @Torsen, you got it right.

Comment: before getting the records you have to select one value from the names list ¿Is it ok?

Comment: @Torsen,  what do you mean by select here?

Comment: You have to know that Salesforce has limits with the queries. You only can run 100 queries per execution. This limit affects that your name list has more than 100 items your code will throw an exception. Another limit is that you can only get 50k records for all the queries.  How @david-reed answered you in the other post, your requirement doesn't look like to have sense.

Comment: This is really the same as the previous question - you're not required to accept my answer there if you don't find it helpful. Please also do not post under two accounts. You can have Stack Exchange merge them by clicking the contact link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like that:

But I don't recommend you to use

```
public static Map<String,SObject[]> getSobjectsByName (String[] objectNames){
        Map<String,SObject[]> sobjectsByName = new Map<String,SObject>();
        for(String objectname : objectNames){
            sobjectsByName.put(objectname, Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM '+objectname));
        }

        return sobjectsByName;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that there will be a Name field on an object?

Comment: yes, I am sure. All the records have an Id and a name field. The name field could be could be an autonumber

Comment: @Torsen Incorrect. "Name" is not present on the Case object.